# How can my shapeshifting superhero best prepare to fight crime?

Tags: technology, super-powers, shapeshifters

Dave lives in a world where superpowers are extremely common, lending to the creation of superpowered crime fighters to combat the superpowered crime doers. What makes Dave special is that he has a unique ability, he can mimic the form of anyone whose blood he consumes while said blood is in his stomach. This even goes as far as to allow him to copy the powers of those whose form he assumes.

While this initially struck him as a perfect power to fight crime, now that he's begun his quest to fight crime, he's quickly learned how unreliable his ability is. As he needs the blood of others, he'll need a consistent way of getting that blood: in addition he has no idea what medical conditions he is going to be stuck with while mimicking the target. To add to the chaotic mix, there's no way of predicting what abilities the superpowered criminal he's fighting will have and in turn, what ability he will be copying.

All in all, Dave needs to be even more prepared than any other superhero. He'll need not only a method of extracting his opponent's blood, but also a uniform that will allow him to take advantage of whatever dice roll he gets when copying someone and their abilities.

To put it shortly, how can Dave best ready himself before engaging in crime fighting, to best insure his safety and success?

As requested in the comments, some clarification on the nature of Dave's ability:

- Dave requires non-coagulated human blood to be able to transform into someone.
- As the effect only lasts while the blood is in his stomach, each dosage typically lasts him more or less 20 minutes. The effect cannot be canceled or stopped short of knocking Dave out or the time limit passing.
- Dave's job as a Superhero pays well, but he'd gladly put himself through another job if it aided him in his Hero work.

Comment: Prisoner A: "Someone looks like my mother beats me up and here I am, how's that." Prisoner B: "I... [blushing] I say that hello kitty is strong... doctor gave me 33 stitches... "

Comment: Isn't this a story-based question? The "best solution" will always be dependent on the circumstances of each situation - unless what you're asking should be answered, "Dave has five dozen vials of blood on hand from a variety of willing donors, a suit full of vampire tech that would make the Borg jealous, and a backpack with a world-class medical kit that can adapt to everything but stage-4 cancer."

Comment: can dave mimic animals, can Dave work at a bloodbank, does the blood need to be fresh?   Food typically can stay in the stomach for 2-8 hours, liquids like blood can last as little of 20 minutes, can he mix the blood with fiber and fat to prolong how long it will sit in the stomach.

Comment: This is a question about Himiko Toga from My Hero Academia, isn't it? The power and world situation is nearly identical.

Comment: You can say what you like, but this is an [exact copy of that weeb shit](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Himiko_Toga#Paranormal_Liberation_War_Arc). Anyway, queries about that kind of weeb shit are off topic here. Take it to SciFi & Fantasy. VTC

Comment: @JBH No. It's a worldbuilding question. Given someone with this ability the question is how do they ensure they have a ready supply of the right blood to operate as a superhero. The shapeshifting is one worldbuilding rule, so the question asks how to make this work as a superhero. You will find how to make something work is permissible in the criteria for apparently story-based questions.

Comment: @a4android If the question is "how to I design my suit such that my superhero can collect blood as he/she fights?" then I agree. The suit represents a substantial limitation (you can only add so much to it) and therefore it's possible to identify a best-answer. If the question, as stated, is "how does my superhero best prepare?" That's 100% dependent on the circumstances. Circumstance dependency = story-based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Dave will mimic his allies.**

How the heck are you going to get the blood of your enemy?  What are you, Nosferatu?  Plus what good it is to mimic your enemy?  Maybe if Dave was a spy master that would be useful but if he is duking it out with Dude, Dude is not going to hold back because Dave looks just like him.  Dude knows Dave is not Dude and will make this clear with kickings and punchings.

No, you need a bunch of little canisters of preserved blood from folks you know. Ask them nicely and do them favors, and collect the blood in a clean medical facility.   People with good powers.  Strong dudes.  Ninja masters.  Little old ladies.  Harmless kids.  High ranking worldbuilders.  All of those, perhaps arranged for easy access in a Chewbacca type bandolier.

Comment: Probably, the best favor he can do them is to help preserve secret identities by allowing them to appear in both identities in the same place.